# Confusion in the definition of left-hand and right-hand limit

Tags: real-analysis, limits, analysis

In Understanding Analysis, the right-hand limit is defined as

**Definition 4.6.2.** Given a limit point $c$ of a set $A\subseteq \mathbb R$ and a function $F :A \to \mathbb R$, we write $$\lim_{x\to c^+} f(x) = L$$ if for all $\epsilon > 0$ there exists a $\delta > 0$ such that $|f(x) - L| < \epsilon$ whenever $0 < x-c < \delta$.

I think the requirement that $c$ is a limit point of $A$ is not strong enough for the right-hand limit to be well defined, because if $(c,\infty) \cap A$ is empty and $c$ is a limit point of $A$ (which is possible consider $A = [0,1]$ and $c = 1$), then any real number can be the right-hand limit for $f$ at $c$.

Can anyone tell me whether I am correct at this?

Maybe we can add definitions for "left limit points" and "right limit point" to solve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with your concerns, and I think that we ought to require that $c$ is a limit point of $(c,\infty)\cap A$ rather than a limit point of $A$ (and similarly for left-hand limits).